# Automating the Configuration Process Of Beacons

Tags: ibeacon, iot, beacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am working on a IoT Project, where I need to deploy 700 beacons in different parts of the country.

Whenever a user(assuming the required services are enabled on the user's phone), the user should get a silent notification of a link to a webapp and if there's an Android/iOS app(for registered users) it would display an update notification.

I have implemented this functionality, so that's already done.

My problem is I have to configure every single beacon manually, which I would like to get it done via a script or an API, because there's a possibility I may have to do the same for 1000+ beacons.

I am using [RadBeacon Dot Beacons](https://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-dot)

Configuration Process Details:

- [Configuration Doc Of Beacons](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0481/4309/files/Configuring_for_Nearby.pdf?5804442401336090297)
- [Configuration through the Beacon App](https://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-config)
- [Setup a Google Nearby Beacon](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/how-to-set-up-google-nearby-beacons/)

How can I automate the entire configuration process for both Android & iOS ?

Little guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would email or call support at Radius Networks and ask if you can get access to a private SDK to configure your beacons for iOS, MacOS or Android.

If you can get your hands on such a SDK, you could build an iOS, MacOS or Android app that does all of these configuration steps.  You will still, however, need to put each RadBeacon Dot into configuration mode one by one and wait for your custom configuration app to connect via bluetooth and configure the beacon.  Since bluetooth connections can be a bit finicky, this might take 5 secs or more with retries.  So best case scenario, you're  talking 5 secs x 700 = one hour to get them all configured.

You'll also have to account for the time it takes you to write the config app and debug it until it is working reliably and as quickly as possible. I have lots of experience with these kinds of apps, and would expect it to take me at least 8 hours, probably much more.  So the best case level of effort to get all beacons configured is 9 hours.

The alternative, of course, is to train an intern (or your little sister) to do this manually, and pay him or her for the trouble.  If you can get all these manual steps done in 45 seconds, doing 700 of them will take a little less than 9 hours -- faster!